# Cloning a Collection in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking to allow certain users to clone a collection, and all of it's child collections and folders to a new 'parent' collection.

I think I've got the overall design down, but after reading many timeout issues, I wanted to see if anyone here has any 'gotcha' things to stick clear of.  I'm going to allow them to select a single collection from a Listbox and give them the chance to name the new 'parent' Collection and the folder it should belong to.

However, where I'm concerned is that iterating through parent>Collection1>Collection2>Collection3.. etc.

I'm thinking of feeding the folders into arrays then create the new folder and then copy docs from source to the new folder.  Sound reasonable?  Anyone already invent this wheel?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any gotchas here. But depending on how many collections and files you're copying, you might hit some of the [various quotas](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard) we're limited too.

I don't if this fits in your use-case, but you might have to divide your workload into minor chunks and do it in multiple runs, setting your script to continue later (depending on the quota, the next day) using the [Script Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_script) API.

Comment: We're looking at taking the stucture of a Collection as a template for projects. Each sub-collection would have no more than 20 docs per sub-collection.  My guess, is a total of 300 docs AT MOST.  So it sounds like it's well within quota.

Thanks...

Comment: If you're using a Google Apps account you will probably be able to copy your collection once a day (500 doc create / day). But you might hit the script total execution time, as it's likely going to take more than 5 minutes. So you'll have to split it and trigger again in the next minute. You should also try-catch the document creation, so if/when you hit the quota, you know where you stopped and can schedule the script for the next day.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a try-catch set of logic.. thanks for the heads up.. I'll look around for some example code...